# Restore folder of icons to home screen

Tags: app-icons

My one year old was playing Balloon Pop on my Pixel 2 and accidentally removed a folder of icons from my Home screen. There happened to be 11 icons in that folder and I'm hoping I can easily get it back without rebuilding it manually? (Some sort of undo function or "trash" area?)

As a side note, any recommendations on how to lock the home screen icons? The icons tend to get accidentally moved a lot, though this is the first time they got completely removed.

Comment: What launcher do you use?

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio - default Pixel launcher. I think I know the answer to the side note now. :)